# What causes the Visual Studio Debugger to make some issues not reproducible?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

Environment: I have a .NET 4.0 solution that references some Visual C++ projects. Visual Studio 2010.

If I build my solution and run the resulting .exe right from the bin directory, I can reproduce my bug. But if I run it hitting the "play" button in Visual Studio (or if I run the process and attach to it) I can step through the code, and everything works as normal.

For reference, the problem I'm getting is an Access Violation which is most definitely happening the C++ code.

**But more broadly, I'm wondering what other reasons there might be that attaching a debugger to a process "fixes" the issue.**

Comment: something wrong with the heap. Compile your code in Release mode and debug it in VS

Comment: Running the green "play" button will use the IDE's environment.  

Executing from the directory will use the default environment.  My guess is that there are probably some DLL's or dependencies that need to be added (directory paths) to your %PATH% environment variable.  @Matt, I don't believe that this is a heap issue - for C++ you'll want to debug in DEBUG compiled configuration.

Comment: Another tricky thing. The issue is only reproducible in Release mode. But when I debug it in Release mode, the problem goes away.

Comment: It could be a timing issue.   E.g. a race condition caused by a background thread.  When you step through your code it gives the background thread time to work.  When run normally, the background thread isn't completing in time.

Comment: (You could test that by putting liberal sleeps in your code, and seeing if the problem goes away - obviously don't be tempted to just call that a fix and leave the sleeps in there!!)

Comment: @matrixugly - Being reproduce-able in only one configuration usually tells me that you're referencing debug libs or missing paths to release libraries... I'd check using dependency walker

Comment: @Huytard, just ran the depends.exe... Nothing seems out of the ordinary. That still doesn't explain why the debug executable works.

Comment: @benjymous - That was my first suspicion exactly! But come to find out that there is only one thread in this part of the code :(

Comment: I don't suppose it is also reproducible using a different debugger, such as WinDbg, which though considerably less flash than the IDE integrated debugger, is actually considerably more powerful.

Comment: You may be running under a different security context debug IN Visual Studio.

Comment: @matrixugly - What about the case where the executable links to the wrong DLL?  i.e. DLLs (one debug, one release) with the same name

Comment: @Huytard it is only occurred in release mode, this is the sign of heap errors.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/reiley/archive/2011/08/28/side-effects-of-debugger.aspx

Comment: Here was the problem for my specific issue
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/611716/c-cli-class-static-constructor-not-called-in-release-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and short answer. **Run Windows Updates.**

The correct and long answer.

It turns out my build machine hasn't been updated in a while and was using an outdated version of Visual C++ compiler. There was a bug in the compiler for .NET 4 where static constructors were not getting called first before any other types of constructors (only in Release Mode).

But here's the kicker!
If you run the process in the Visual Studio debugger OR you attach to a remote process. The static constructors DO get called first like they are supposed to! (Hence making the issue completely un-reproducible in a debugging environment -- Even in Release mode) I found the issue by placing message boxes all over the place to determine the code path.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/611716/c-cli-class-static-constructor-not-called-in-release-build

Answer (score 3):

- MS VS is working like a sandbox. When you are starting app in that sandbox, your program inherits all settings from solution properties (or just VS settings). Make sure, all your options provided for the environment are correct. If that wont solve the problem, please double check those settings and think what can prevent access violation and uncheck/check it.
- If you are using external DLL, those from you system and those from IDE may have different version. They, of course, may work in both cases, but also may cause problem like access violation or subcribent out of range, depending what is changed inside those dlls.
- If its Windows app, try enabling/disabling `LargeAddressAware`.
- If you are compiling stuff for another machine with different OS, it may happen very often due to changes in memory handling by native OS. Memory can sometimes be multi-blocked, extremely fragmented or even multi-deviced, so compile your program only with compilation especially made for targeted OS/machine
- debug mode uses assert() and other stuff directly linked to debugging. If something is wrong in debugging and not in release, it means that it is acceptable by machine but not by debugging insertions. In that case you are screwed but if its not appear to be problem in other debugger, well... problem solved, its debugger issue, espeially if release without debugging options is working.
- most tiring method - try to pinpoint access violation address and see inside memory windows to what are you referring.
- in other cases, supply us with snippet, so we can tell something more!

---

@Matt this cant be heap problem, it can happen but its extremely rare.

@Huytard its wont happen, without linked dll's program should't even start.

Comment: How do you enable LargeAddressAware?

Comment: its working only for x64 and <3Gb ram, for the rest try PropertyPages>Linker>System>enable LAA for this build
you have very little chances to fix address violation by this but its worth trying

Comment: @Matt
yes but this is very large field to fail. You can do almost anything to corrupt heap if you are not careful. I assume that if he is working on .net he can take care of bad pointer :9

Answer (score 0):

1. Running the green "play" button will use the [IDE's environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)
2. Executing from the directory will use the [default environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

My **guess** is that there are probably some DLL's or dependencies that need to be added (directory paths) to your %PATH% environment variable.

Once you identify the dependencies and double check or something with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) - you can set them in a batch script and then call your application.

For example:

```
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\myLibs
call MyApp.exe
```